# How do i get started with Android?

Tags: android

How should i get started with Android? From where do i get help and sample source code? Can a JSF application run on Android phones? I saw primefaces site and it has TouchFaces which are meant for Android phones. But i really don't know how should i get started with Android. Is it too tough? Does it take too much time creating even a simple application?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to learn developing Android applications](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3211193/how-to-learn-developing-android-applications)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recently started with Android development. The official Android development site has some good stuff to get you started:

http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/hello-world.html

http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/index.html

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

Now, whenever I'm stuck on a particular aspect of a program, I just use Google to search for what I'm trying to do. I've learned that just about everything has been done and blogged about. For that matter, a bunch of the answers that I've needed have been here on SO.

Answer (score 3):

There are a bunch of questions related to this. Just to name a few:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2272764/where-to-start-with-programming-android-applications
- [starting with android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2666964/starting-with-android)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949818/how-can-i-learn-android
- [Start Learning Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2902134/start-learning-android)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1733401/android-learning-the-platform-have-any-app-suggestions
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3211193/how-to-learn-developing-android-applications

Answer (score 2):

If you are worried that it might be too complicated, try [Android App Inventor](http://appinventor.googlelabs.com/about/). It provides a GUI for building Android apps out of prebuilt modules.
It also comes with its own set of [tutorials](http://appinventor.googlelabs.com/learn/tutorials/index.html).

Comment: Is it possible to get a usable Eclipse project out of an Android App Inventor? i.e. so that you can continue to extend it further?

Comment: I don't use Eclipse, but you can download your source (see http://appinventor.googlelabs.com/learn/tutorials/hellopurr/HelloPurrAssets/HelloPurrDesigner.png for screenshot), so I would imagine so.

Answer (score 1):

Start with the android developer tutorials

http://developer.android.com/resources/index.html

It is pretty simple to make apps. The way individual screens are made is a different paradigm than either a Java swing app, or a Java web app... but not so far away that it won't make sense.

Answer (score 1):

The most helpful starting point for me was to reading the "Hello, Android" book from the Pragmatic Bookshelf:
http://www.pragprog.com/titles/eband3/hello-android

I've posted the link to the third edition (*edit: now published*) which will deal with Android up to version 2.1 (2.2+ to follow, I'd guess!).  However, if you're already asking questions on JSF etc. this may be too basic - then I'd agree with most of the other answers and browse the web for more information.

However, I found the book a quick read, and by running through a few of the sample apps included I was soon able to start work on one of my own.  Basically, whatever gets you coding quickest with a reasonable understanding of what to do...

Answer (score 1):

After you get into Android, You need to learn how to Debug in Eclipse and how to use the [ADB](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb) and [DDMS](https://web.archive.org/web/20120618172953/http://developer.android.com:80/guide/developing/tools/ddms.html) tools.

In order to get more details about an exception/force close you need to look for a view in Eclipse called [Logcat](https://web.archive.org/web/20100324231958/http://developer.android.com:80/intl/de/guide/developing/debug-tasks.html)(you will find in the [DDMS](https://web.archive.org/web/20170825232742/http://www.brighthub.com:80/mobile/google-android/articles/25023.aspx) perspective) there you will find a detailed traceback when/what and on what line is the issue.

For this you should read a complete article about [Debugging in Android using Eclipse](http://www.droidnova.com/debugging-in-android-using-eclipse,541.html)

[image]
<sub>(source: [droidnova.com](http://www.droidnova.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2009/09/debugging-3.gif))</sub>

Answer (score 1):

http://www.vogella.de/articles/Android/article.html#installation_androidsdk

best application guide to start with..

Go For It!!

Answer (score 1):

You may also want to check this "**Android UI design patterns**"

http://code.google.com/events/io/2010/sessions/android-ui-design-patterns.html